# Need Xpath for button in HTML tags

Tags: html, xpath, selenium-webdriver, html-table

Application HTML tags with  INPUT id=Submit1. System return error for all Xpaths in IE/HTML driver. I don't find error in Firefox/Chrome .

```
    //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='submit']")).click();
    //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//textarea[@name='Textarea1']/input[1]")).click();
    //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//textarea[input/@name='submit1']")).click();
    //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='submit1'][@type='submit']")).click();
    //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='submit1']/input[1]")).click();
    /driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/article/div/table/tbody/tr["+1+"]/td["+1+"]")).getText();
    //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/input[@value='submit']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@value='submit']/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]")).click();


<BODY style="FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma"><P>&nbsp;</P>
<P>
<TABLE style="POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 784px; FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma; TOP: 5px; LEFT: 5px">
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #3c4482; WIDTH: 768px"><IMG src="http://www.commidea.com/images/layup/logo.gif"></TD>
<TD vAlign=top align=left></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD style="WIDTH: 768px"><BR>Standard Txn Authorisation Request Request:<BR><BR><TEXTAREA onblur="return Textarea1_onblur()" style="WIDTH: 800px; HEIGHT: 240px" id=Textarea1 name=Textarea1>&lt;?xml version="1.0"?&gt;
&lt;soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"&gt;
&lt;soap:Body&gt;
&lt;ProcessMsg xmlns="https://www.commidea.webservices.com"&gt;
&lt;Message&gt;
    &lt;ClientHeader xmlns="https://www.commidea.webservices.com"&gt;
        &lt;SystemID&gt;7140&lt;/SystemID&gt;
        &lt;SystemGUID&gt;B6DCE5B6-B2FC-472B-9C79-407FF8005994&lt;/SystemGUID&gt;
        &lt;Passcode&gt;44275733&lt;/Passcode&gt;
        &lt;ProcessingDB&gt;UK5MIDB025V3A1&lt;/ProcessingDB&gt;
        &lt;SendAttempt&gt;0&lt;/SendAttempt&gt;
    &lt;/ClientHeader&gt;
&lt;MsgType xmlns="https://www.commidea.webservices.com"&gt;TXN&lt;/MsgType&gt;
&lt;MsgData xmlns="https://www.commidea.webservices.com"&gt;
&lt;![CDATA[&lt;transactionrequest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="TXN"&gt;
    &lt;merchantreference&gt;TEST&lt;/merchantreference&gt;
    &lt;accountid&gt;14614&lt;/accountid&gt;
    &lt;txntype&gt;01&lt;/txntype&gt;
    &lt;transactioncurrencycode&gt;826&lt;/transactioncurrencycode&gt;
    &lt;apacsterminalcapabilities&gt;4298&lt;/apacsterminalcapabilities&gt;
    &lt;capturemethod&gt;11&lt;/capturemethod&gt;
    &lt;processingidentifier&gt;1&lt;/processingidentifier&gt;
    &lt;tokenid&gt;0&lt;/tokenid&gt;
    &lt;pan&gt;4485123123123123&lt;/pan&gt;
    &lt;track2&gt;&lt;/track2&gt;
    &lt;csc&gt;&lt;/csc&gt;
    &lt;avshouse&gt;&lt;/avshouse&gt;
    &lt;avspostcode&gt;&lt;/avspostcode&gt;
    &lt;expirydate&gt;0912&lt;/expirydate&gt;
    &lt;issuenumber&gt;&lt;/issuenumber&gt;
    &lt;startdate&gt;&lt;/startdate&gt;
    &lt;txnvalue&gt;9.50&lt;/txnvalue&gt;
    &lt;cashback&gt;0.00&lt;/cashback&gt;
    &lt;gratuity&gt;0.00&lt;/gratuity&gt;
    &lt;authcode&gt;&lt;/authcode&gt;
    &lt;transactiondatetime&gt;&lt;/transactiondatetime&gt;
    &lt;vgistransaction&gt;0&lt;/vgistransaction&gt;
&lt;/transactionrequest&gt;]]&gt;&lt;/MsgData&gt;
&lt;/Message&gt;
&lt;/ProcessMsg&gt;
&lt;/soap:Body&gt;
&lt;/soap:Envelope&gt;</TEXTAREA><BR><INPUT id=Submit1 onclick="return Submit1_onclick()" value=submit type=submit><BR></TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 3px"></TD>
<TD></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD style="WIDTH: 768px; HEIGHT: 110px"><BR>Standard Txn Authorisation Request Response:<BR><BR><TEXTAREA style="WIDTH: 800px; HEIGHT: 153px" id=TextArea2></TEXTAREA></TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 3px; HEIGHT: 110px"></TD>
<TD style="HEIGHT: 110px"></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></P>
<P>&nbsp;</P></BODY>
```

Please help me how to give Xpath for HTML tags. I reviewed some google but didn't help for my html structure tags

Comment: Given the element you're trying to find has an `id`, why not skip the XPath and just use `By.id` instead?

Comment: Did you tell us what the error message was?

Answer (score 0):

if locators working on FF/Chrome and not on IE then it can not be coding issue. Try putting up some extra waits at locations where IE fails. I faced similar situation once and extra waits solved it